# Eclipse-mosquitto 2.0.x: websocket publish OK subscribe NOK, no message received

Tags: eclipse, websocket, mosquitto

I'm using eclipse-mosquitto 1.6.15 on 1883 (internal), 8883 (external) and via a websocket on 9001 for displaing data on a webserver.

Everything's fine with 1.6.15 but I want to enable TLS 1.3 for cybersecurity reasons. Hence I want to migrate to the 2.0.X in which, I believe, the TLS 1.3 was introduced.

I have a specific internal websocket configuration

```
listener 9001
protocol websockets
auth_opt_jwt_alg HS256
auth_opt_jwt_sec_base64 TOKEN
auth_opt_jwt_validate_exp false
auth_opt_jwt_validate_sub_match_username false
```

Note for later that I also tried with

```
listener 9001 0.0.0.0
socket_domain ipv4
```

When I connect my web application I can see that the subscribe is working fine

```
1696498621: Client client_old_XXX closed its connection. <= on a refrsh 
1696498621:  -- [wsisrv|1f|adopted] (0) 2.066min
1696498622:  ++ [wsisrv|20|adopted] (1)
1696498625: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1696498625:  -- [wsisrv|20|adopted] (0) 3.078s
1696498627: New client connected from IP:PORT as client_new_XXX (p1, c1, k65535, u'configurator').
1696498627: No will message specified.
1696498627: Sending CONNACK to client_new_XXX (0, 0)
1696498628: Received SUBSCRIBE from client_new_XXX
1696498628:     /control/+/+/+ (QoS 0)
1696498628: Sending SUBACK to client_new_XXX
1696498628: Received SUBSCRIBE from client_new_XXX
1696498628:     /state/+/+/+ (QoS 0)
1696498628: Sending SUBACK to client_new_XXX
1696498628: Received SUBSCRIBE from client_new_XXX
1696498628:     /telemetry/+/+/+ (QoS 0)
1696498628: Sending SUBACK to client_new_XXX
```

client_new_XXX == unique client ID

The websocket remain active and I can publish messages without any issue. The main problem is that no messages are received via the websocket (via the network WSS debug console on firefox). I only see the published ones.

I'm suspecting a subtle change in the eclipse-mosquitto 2.0.x version but I'm not finding the evidence...

Another possibility is that the version of libwebsockets (with is 4.2.1) is messing with the websocket connectivity. I read that moving back to libwebsockets v3.x.x can fix this  but I'm not sure how to downgrade this lib since I'm using the official docker image release by the eclipse-mosquitto team.

Any advice/idea ?

For now I rollback to 1.6.15 and only allow TLS 1.2.

Best,

Florian

By using eclipse-mosquitto 2.0.x I was expecting the websocket to allows my web application to publish messages and to received the messages from the subscribed topics.

While the published messages are correctly send, the websocket is not receiving anything.

I tried to update my mosquitto.conf by adding

```
listener 9001 0.0.0.0
socket_domain ipv4
```

Comment: What happens if you enable debug/verbose logging on the broker, do you see 1) any messages round the subscription 2) any attempt to the publish the message to the client?

Comment: Hi, in the mosquitto config file I already have "log_type all". No specific message around the subscription except the ones I put in my initial message. No connection error. When I publish a message from my web application the message is correctly published on the broker, I'm directly logged in on the broker and subscribed to /#